# Android studio navigation drawer not handling clicks

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to have a navigation drawer that replaces a frame layout with a fragment on a navigation item click.  Here's my code for the drawer...

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        case R.id.things_manager:
            ThingsManager thingsManager = new ThingsManager();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, thingsManager).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.settings_tab:
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, settings).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.sign_out_tab:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The nav menu pops up when I click the menu icon, but none of the item clicks work.  Not even the sign out intent that I have at the bottom.

Comment: Assuming your drawer is a `NavigationView`, its menu has no relation to the options menu, which is what `onOptionsItemSelected()` handles. You'll need to implement an `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, and [set it on the `NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)), to get clicks on its menu items.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
android.support.v4.app.Fragment myFragment = null;
Class fragmentClass = null;

switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        //Example if your fragment activity name is fragment_home
          fragmentClass = fragment_home.class;
          break;

    case R.id.things_manager:
        //Same as Home
        break;

    case R.id.settings_tab:
        //
        break;

    case R.id.sign_out_tab:
        //
        break;
}
try{
        myFragment = (android.support.v4.app.Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    //Back Button Wont Kill
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();


return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you have `Drawer` already implemented I assume you have already declared `NavigationView` in your `Activity`. If haven't already.

Implement `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` in your `Activity`.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {....}
```

Add this in your `onCreate` of `Activity`

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Add this method in your `Activity` to handle clicks on Drawer items.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;

        case R.id.things_manager:
            ThingsManager thingsManager = new ThingsManager();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, thingsManager).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.settings_tab:
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, settings).commit();
            return true;

        case R.id.sign_out_tab:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
    }

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```